# How are strings replaced with variables from tables?

Tags: magento-1.9

For example, an extension would have this: 
`Variable {day} will be replaced with the estimated delivery value from the corresponding CSV column` under an input field. 
 I understand that it probably works in a similar way as translations, but how exactly can I replace `{day}` with a variable from a table in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out myself!
This is done by `str_replace`. 
More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php